# Assign Microsoft Office 365 Administrator Role to User with Office 365 API?

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

Is it possible to assign a user as an Office 365 admin using the office 365 API?  I am able to create/edit users and assign licences, but I did not see a role property in the API documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: Do you mean a global admin? Or some other, segmented, admin role? You can assign roles programmatically via PowerShell: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/powershell/assign-roles-to-user-accounts-with-office-365-powershell but I'm not familiar with the Graph API.

Comment: Related: [Adding users to Exchange admin role groups via API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40935849/adding-users-to-exchange-admin-role-groups-via-api)